# jQuery resizable - alsoresize rect in svg through outer div control

Tags: jquery-ui, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

HTML:

```
<svg width="400" height="110" 
     style="background:red">
 <rect id="rectangle" width="300" height="100" 
   style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
 </svg>

 <div id="firstDiv" 
      style="width:100px;height:100px; background:green">
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 jQuery('#firstDiv').resizable({
        handles: 'se',
        animate: true,
        alsoResize: '#rectangle',
    })
```

With this sample, The **rect** inside **svg** always starting from x=0, y=0 when we resize **firstDiv**.

Rect has to start from where it was its last starting/ending position not from zero

jquery ui version : jQuery UI - v1.12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our resizable method add following code

```
jQuery('#firstDiv').resizable({
        handles: 'se',
        animate: true,
        alsoResize: '#rectangle',    
        resize: function (event, ui) {
           document.querySelector('#rectangle').style.width = ui.size.width;
           document.querySelector('#rectangle').style.height = ui.size.height;
        }
   });
```

Now everything works fine